# Word to describe "something which makes it compatible" "compabilitizer?"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word for the term "something which makes it compatible". Can I use *compatibilizer*?

Google search reveals this term is used in chemistry but is it used in other contexts? **Is the *-izer* suffix sufficiently productive** that what might be jargon could be understood elsewhere?

Comment: We don't do naming, so I've removed that and made an ELU question about the *-ize/-izer* suffix, which is probably more on-topic and answerable. [We don't do naming because a class named `susan` would work just as well as one named `which_makes_things_compatible`. What you are *actually* asking about is the word itself, not a name.]

Comment: A specific context would be of great help, here.

Comment: Do you want a term for an attribute of the thing itself, or the name of something used to adapt one thing to another.?

Comment: 'Harmoniser' is altogether better known as a word, and broadening it to include non-sentient agents has doubtless already been done. You could check in a Google search (online dictionaries don't seem to mention non-sentient-agent usage). // 'Productivity' is determined by usage, rather than the other way round.

Comment: to align one thing with another, too.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I would take 'Harmoniser' to mean something that brings two things into harmony, which doesn't really mean the same as 'compatible': It's lovely and poetic, but it wouldn't make immediate sense to me if I read it in the context of compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

*Adapter* is pretty widely used for such things. (As in an electrical adapter that makes an appliance compatible with the sockets in a different country).